# How to Set Timeout on WebClient call?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the classic:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();                    
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml";
webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(inputMessage.Namespace, UriKind.Absolute), inputMessage.ToXML());
webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(ProcessResponse)
```

;

But I want to set the timeout of the request to something lower.
My googling directed me to use HttpWebRequest, but i liked the WebClient API. I ended up extending WebClient and overriding a protected method there that would create the underlying HttpWebRequest:

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri) {
            HttpWebRequest result = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            result.Timeout = someTimeOut;
            return result;
        }
```

Problem is in WP7 the HttpWebRequest has no property for setting the Timeout, that is just in normal .NET.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of how to implement your own timeout at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/80504/423951.aspx

There is no built-in way to have a timeout.

Comment: Nope. In Silverlight, both the WebClient class and the WebRequest class (which WebClientt uses internally) has no timeout property. So that article is not helpful, really. Perhaps the article has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries instead of Silverlight's built-in option.

https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.1.10

Answer (score -2):

That's by design. The WebClient does not have a timeout property. It's just a wrapper class to the WebRequest...IMO it's just boxing. One of the nice things about the WebClient is that it uses Events and not AsynCallbacks...in the end both Class use the BrowserHttpWebRequest. You could just use the HttpWebRequest and avoid the extension...as you did.

Comment: The problem is that HttpWebrequest does not have a Timeout property.

Comment: On Windows Phone 7 ClientHttp is used not BrowserHttp.  BrowserHttp uses the http stack provided by the host browser, on WP7 there is no host browser.